# How the fix washed-off wall paint?

Tags: walls, paint

I've recently moved to a new place and I wanted to clean a couple of superficial wall stains like I always did: using a clean cloth and a few drops of water. But apparently this wall paint is different (non-washable?) than in my previous apartment and I was left with this permanent damage:

[image: Wall stain after cleaning]

Any idea what is the problem? And how to fix it decently without having to repaint the entire wall - I'm thinking spray paint or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That almost looks like a sprayed on primer and not "real" paint. Your best bet would be to get a small can of primer and roll it on the wall, feathering it in to the surrounding area. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you mean walls were not painted properly? It's a relatively new house with generally good quality finishing, so I'd be surprised.

Comment: The walls were prepared properly, I just think maybe the previous owner didn't paint the wall.  After drywall is installed, the builders will spray/roll on the paint primer that's a flat white finish.  They don't then paint the wall, that's up to the buyers.  They might choose to paint some walls and leave other walls primer white.  This spot looks like a primer white wall.

Comment: It will be highly improbable to get an aesthetic match to paint.